# How to use 3d lookup table and map its pixel value to an image?

Tags: opengl, image-processing, glsl, core-image

I'm trying to apply a png color table to an image, but can't match the pixel from the png to the target image.

The color table is a png of 64^3

[image]

[image]

From what I understand each pixel in the larget image, need to use a similar value in the color table. This seem to limit the colors to 262144 = 64 x 64 x 64. But I'm not sure that this was the effect that I was getting, the results are a completely black image which mean no value, or very strange look colors.

This is my code

```
// The table is 64 x 64 x 64
float size = 64.0;

// This is the original image
// This function returns a pixel value inside a 3d space
//  and the `rgb` method will return a vector with the rgb values
vec3 source_image = sample(src_i, samplerCoord(src_i)).rgb;
// Here I take the pixel value of the image for the red channel
//  and multiply it by 64.0, then divide by 255.0 for the 8-bit image
float x = floor(floor(source_image.r * size)/255.0);
// The same thing for the green value on the y axis
float y = floor(floor(source_image.g * size)/255.0);

// Match a value from the image in the color table
vec3 color = sample(src_l, vec2(x, y)).rgb;

src_i.r = color.r;
src_i.g = color.g;
// The blue should be on the z axis, or the nth tile, so I think for this
//   case it will be easier to convert the color table to one long row
src_i.b = floor(floor(source_image.b * size)/255.0);

// The image is black
```

Original image

[image]

Expected result

[image]

If I multiply by 255 instead (which seems right), then I get this result

```
float x = floor(source_image.r * 255.0);
float y = floor(source_image.g * 255.0);
```

[image]

I would really appreciate if you can point out what is wrong with the math

Comment: Is the pixel value, I will edit this part. Thanks for adding the photos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lookup table is not 64*64*64, but it is 64*64 in an 8*8 raster. The color channels which are read by `texture2D` are in range [0, 1] and the texture coordinates are in range [0, 1 ], too.

```c
vec2 tiles    = vec2(8.0);
vec2 tileSize = vec2(64.0);

vec3 imageColor = texture(src_i, samplerCoord(src_i)).rgb;
```

The index of the tile is encoded to the blue color channel. There are 64 tiles, the first tile has the index 0 and the last tile has the index 63. This means that the blue color channel in the range [0, 1] has to be mapped to the the range [0, 63]:

```c
float index = imageColor.b * (tiles.x * tiles.y - 1.0);
```

Form this linear tile index the 2 dimensional tile index has in range [0, 8] has to be calculated:

```c
vec2 tileIndex;
tileIndex.y = floor(index / tiles.x);
tileIndex.x = floor(index - tileIndex.y * tiles.x);
```

The texture minifying function ([`GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml)) and texture magnification function ([`GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml) should be set to [`GL_LINEAR`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml). This causes that the colors on each tile can be linear interpolated.
Each tile has 64x64 texels. The relative coordinate of the lower left texel is (0.5/64.0, 0.5/64.0) and the relative coordinate of the upper right texel is (63.5/64.0, 63.5/64.0).
The red and green color channel in the range [0, 1] have to be mapped to the range [0.5/64.0, 63.5/64.0]:

```c
vec2 tileUV = mix(0.5/tileSize, (tileSize-0.5)/tileSize, imageColor.rg);
```

Finally the texture coordinate for the color look up table in the range [0, 1] c an be calculated:

```c
vec2 tableUV = tileIndex / tiles + tileUV / tiles;
```

The final code which decodes the color in the fragment shader may look like this:

```c
vec2 tiles    = vec2(8.0, 8.0);
vec2 tileSize = vec2(64.0);

vec4 imageColor = texture(src_i, samplerCoord(src_i));

float index = imageColor.b * (tiles.x * tiles.y - 1.0);

vec2 tileIndex;
tileIndex.y = floor(index / tiles.x);
tileIndex.x = floor(index - tileIndex.y * tiles.x);

vec2 tileUV = mix(0.5/tileSize, (tileSize-0.5)/tileSize, imageColor.rg);

vec2 tableUV = tileIndex / tiles + tileUV / tiles;

vec3 lookUpColor = texture(src_l, tableUV).rgb;
```

This algorithm can be further improved, by interpolating between the 2 tiles of the table. Calculate the index of the tile below the blue color channel and the index of the tile above the blue color channel:

```c
float index     = imageColor.b * (tiles.x * tiles.y - 1.0);
float index_min = min(62.0, floor(index));
float index_max = index_min + 1.0;
```

Finally interpolate between the colors from both tiles by using the [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) function:

```c
vec3 lookUpColor_1 = texture(src_l, tableUV_1).rgb;
vec3 lookUpColor_2 = texture(src_l, tableUV_1).rgb;
vec3 lookUpColor   = mix(lookUpColor_1, lookUpColor_2, index-index_min);
```

Final code:

```c
vec2 tiles    = vec2(8.0, 8.0);
vec2 tileSize = vec2(64.0);

vec4 imageColor = texture(src_i, samplerCoord(src_i));

float index     = imageColor.b * (tiles.x * tiles.y - 1.0);
float index_min = min(62.0, floor(index));
float index_max = index_min + 1.0;

vec2 tileIndex_min;
tileIndex_min.y = floor(index_min / tiles.x);
tileIndex_min.x = floor(index_min - tileIndex_min.y * tiles.x);
vec2 tileIndex_max;
tileIndex_max.y = floor(index_max / tiles.x);
tileIndex_max.x = floor(index_max - tileIndex_max.y * tiles.x);

vec2 tileUV = mix(0.5/tileSize, (tileSize-0.5)/tileSize, imageColor.rg);

vec2 tableUV_1 = tileIndex_min / tiles + tileUV / tiles;
vec2 tableUV_2 = tileIndex_max / tiles + tileUV / tiles;

vec3 lookUpColor_1 = texture(src_l, tableUV_1).rgb;
vec3 lookUpColor_2 = texture(src_l, tableUV_2).rgb;
vec3 lookUpColor   = mix(lookUpColor_1, lookUpColor_2, index-index_min);
```

See the image which compares the original image (top left) and by the color lookup modified image (bottom right):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The calculation for finding the corresponding position in the color table seem to be off. I think you would have to find the offset for landing inside the correct "red-green plane" (determined by the blue channel of the input, with consideration of the stride of 8 due to the 8x8 layout in the map) first, and then add this offset to the calculation of the `x` and `y` value.

However, I would recommend you check out the built-in [`CIColorCube` filter](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorCube) first, because it does exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I didn't find a solution yet. However, it worked with the CIColorCube and horizontal lut instead of a square. But I'm trying to work with and understand the lookup up function