# How do I efficiently look up color values from a list in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, glsles

I have 384 RGB values, all already calculated, and I need a function that takes in any given R, G, and B values and returns true if it is one of the known 384 RGB colors, and false otherwise.

Since I couldn't seem to find how to create dictionaries (if they exist) or multidimensional arrays, I eventually managed to get it to work by creating instantiating 3 different arrays, one for R values, G values, and B values, and then looping through all 384 values every time the function was called. It looks like this:

```
int cR[384] = int[384](254, 254, 165, 254, ... , 233);
int cG[384] = int[384](254, 254,  74, 224, ... ,  62);
int cB[384] = int[384](232, 194,  12, 102, ... ,  12);

bool cExists(int r, int g, int b)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 384; i++)
    {
    if (r == cR[i] && g == cG[i] && b == cB[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This works as intended, but is far too slow and is causing problems elsewhere as a result. To try to speed it up, I tried to make a giant array using bit shifting as a pairing function to create unique keys but got stuck here when I found out that I don't even know the syntax to assign a value to an array (the second line errors and I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the values in an array):

```
bool cRGBHashed[16777216];
cRGBHashed[0] = true;
```

And here was the hash function I was going to use if you're curious:

```
int rgbHash(int r, int g, int b)
{
    return (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
}
```

I'm certain there's room for significant improvement here somehow, but the combination of my lack of knowledge about the language's bells and whistles combined with the lack of easy to follow documentation (since I honestly don't even know what version of GLSL this program is even running) is making this a real headache.

Comment: The usual way is to create a lookup texture. e.g. [How to use 3d lookup table and map its pixel value to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54726995/how-to-use-3d-lookup-table-and-map-its-pixel-value-to-an-image/54730065#54730065)

Comment: I'd make a byte array rather than a bool array so you don't have to do bit testing on the elements. Could be either a 1 dimensional array using your hash function as the index, or a 3D greyscale image/texture indexed directly by red, green, blue.

This would use 16M of memory, but is that going to be a problem? Modern computers have gigabytes to play with.

Comment: @KaiBurjack you do not need any HASH the color is already distinct (24bit) value ... also the naive LUT is just 2MByte as you need just single bit for each color ...

Answer (score 0):

I would perform linear search on the red channel and if an element was found, I would check the other channels for it is the actual color.
Because you might have multiple identical red values you have to still check the "neighbor-numbers" of your red-value, since the identical would be all next to each other, so do some kind of little check-loop in the left and right direction for if one of them would be it.

Answer (score 0):

As @KaiBurjack suggest you can use hashing. As the color is already distinct (24bit) value you can consider it as hash already. So

1. convert all colors to 24 bit ints
2. sort them prior to shader execution
3. in shader just binary `search O(log(n))`

If you want `O(1)` then you need a `bool LUT[256][256][256]` look up table that will tell you if color is present or not but that is 2MByte of data (can be passed as texture)